# not only.. but also

Tags: verbs, idioms, tenses

Why is this sentence incorrect: 
"Not only this transformation changes the preference of respondents, but it also converts the scale"

and I was asked to write: 
"Not only does this transformation change the preference of respondents, but it also converts the scale"

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Fronting an element like "not only" triggers subject-auxiliary inversion. Since there is no auxiliary present here, one has to be inserted, and this is the "dummy" auxiliary "do". Notice the inverted "does this" (not "this does"). Because "do" is an auxiliary verb, the following 'main' verb must be an infinitival, so "change", not "changes".

Comment: @BillJ Hmm. Devil's advocate here: how about "Not only Mary left early."?

Comment: @Araucaria In your example, "not only" is modifying the NP "Mary", but in the OP's example it's modifying a VP. With VPs inversion is triggered when "not only" is fronted, cf. "Ed not only studies three days a week, but he also works part time at McDonalds" vs "Not only does Ed study three days a week, but he also works at McDonalds".

Comment: @BillJ It can be any type of adjunct so long as it isn't modifying the Subject or part of the Subject, methinks.

Comment: @Araucaria You've lost me. I thought you were making a point about inversion?

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I was. My point was that the fronting of a negative adjunct will cause subject-auxiliary inversion so long as it is moved from a non-clause initial position (and fulfils some other semantic requirements). So the *not only* modifying a subject doesn't fulfil this requirement (because it isn't fronted), but fronting of the adjunct *not only* on its own does. Off the top of my head that is. So I was agreeing with your second point, and devil's advocating about your initial comment ;-)

Comment: @BillJ I thought I spotted another comment as I was rushing back to class. Didn't have time to read it ... Was there another grammary point?

Answer (score 1):

This is called **do-support** and is required when you have a negative such as **never** before the subject.

Other examples from Wikipedia:

> Never did he run that fast again. (wrong: *Never he did run that fast again. *Never ran he that fast again.)
>   Only here do I feel at home. (wrong: *Only here feel I at home.)