# "Not only has he got many friends, but also several enemies." "Not only he has many friends, but also several enemies."

Tags: subject-verb-inversion, complex-sentences

"Not only has he got many friends, but also several enemies." 
"Not only he has many friends, but also several enemies."

Which out of the two statements above is correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [not only.. but also](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334945/not-only-but-also)

Comment: The inversion in your first sentence is correct, but the colloquial _has got_  doesn't fit very well. The most (grammatically) correct would be "Not only _does he have_ many friends...".